# how to implement search log?

Tags: ajax, rest, api, search

I have a basic "input search" using AJAX (angularJS, elasticsearch and lumen) and I need to implement the search history for each user in my application. I have some ideas on this:

1. Save the record from the backend every time you call the uri search(maybe this would increase the response time too much).
2. Save each search in the frontend and when changing the pages or after a few seconds, maybe a second, send this dataset to the backend.

What would be the best way to optimize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For searching anyways you are calling the method , then only you can store the search history, I guess first approach is good.

Saving it at frontend first and then again one extra call for saving those search text will not be good idea.

This is my thinking.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your opinion.
I've also been thinking of creating another uri and therefore not overloading the search API(for user experience issues). Do you think that would be a better idea?

Comment: yes. If you have more time you can check the responses of both the approaches.